# Multiple Textbox using a select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i Want a select list, which will increase or decrease the numbers of textbox below it, the user will select 2 in select list, than 2 text box should appear and if he selects 3 than 3. i need the code for it in html and js.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>MAIN</title>
</head>
<script>

function onchange_action(){

  var e=document.getElementsByName("AuthoringForm")[0];
  for(j=1; j<(e.value)+1; j++){

    var x = document.getElementById((j).value);
    console.log(j);
        x.style.display = "none";

    }   
  }


</script>

<body>

<form>
<div id="1">
  <input type="text">hello</input>
</div>
<div id="2">
  <input type="text">hello</input>
</div>
<div id="3">
  <input type="text">hello</input>
</div>
<div id="4">
 <input type="text">hello</input>
</div>
</form>

<select name="AuthoringForm" property="disease_name" size="1" 
onchange="onchange_action();">
    <option selected="selected"> Select Number of Products </option> 
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>


</body>
</html>
```

this is what i have tried so for, but not working.

Comment: And what have you tried, also please remember that StackOverflow is not a coding service

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<title>MAIN</title>
</head>
<script>

function onchange_action(){

var e=document.getElementsByName("AuthoringForm")[0];
for(j=1; j<= e.value; j++){

    document.getElementById(j).style.display='block';

}   

for(; j<5; j++){
document.getElementById(j).style.display='none';    
   }
  }


</script>

<body>

<form>
<div id="1">
  <input type="text">hello</input>
</div>
<div id="2">
  <input type="text">hello</input>
</div>
<div id="3">
  <input type="text">hello</input>
</div>
<div id="4">
  <input type="text">hello</input>
</div>
</form>

<select name="AuthoringForm" property="disease_name" size="1" 
onchange="onchange_action();">
    <option selected="selected"> Select Number of Products </option> 
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>


</body>
</html>
```

:)